# MBProgressHUD issue in main thread.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mbprogresshud

I would like to use `MBProgressHUD` the following way: In my method I call multiple servers and other actions that require showing a **HUD**. I was wondering what would be the best way to "hold" the main thread until those particular actions are done.

For example:

```
method {

MBProgressHUD (action 1) //don't move on until this is done

//some other code...

MBProgressHUD (action 2)

//some other code...

}
```

I am pretty new to iOS so sorry if this is too simple. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `you use graphical change in MBProgressHUD.`

example :-

```
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(fetchNewData) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

fetchNewData will be called on secondary thread . so `no use  graphical change` in MBProgressHUD.

if you want to graphical change use in `hudWasHidden delegete`

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834571/623784) answer, or ask the developer over at [Github](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD). Also, it is never a good idea to block the main-thread.  Call it in a different thread. Go for Grand Central Dispatch.